# Having trouble using dplyr in R to group by then mutate and generate statistic by group

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I have read several other posts where people seem to have had the same problem. I am using the example of the iris dataset. I want to find the max by group but instead it is giving me the max across the whole dataset.

I tried to detach(plyr) because it said to make sure you load dplyr after plyr. I also tried adding dplyr:: before the commands. But neither of those seem to make a difference. I am using dplyr version 1.0.2

This is the code I am using. I am new to posting so not sure how to show the mistake in the data or how to make data show up correctly. This is what I get but max_sepal should be 5.8 for that first group. Thank you for your help!

```
iris_1 <- iris %>%
 dplyr::group_by(Species) %>%
 dplyr::mutate(max_sepal = max(iris$Sepal.Length, na.rm=TRUE))
```

```
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species max_sepal
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>       <dbl>
 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa        7.9
 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa        7.9
 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa        7.9
 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa        7.9
 5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa        7.9
 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa        7.9
 7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa        7.9
 8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa        7.9
 9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa        7.9
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa        7.9
```

Comment: Try with `max(Sepal.Length, na.rm = TRUE)`. `max(iris$Sepal.Length, ..` simply gives the max on the ungrouped dataset.

Comment: @AliData does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. I didn't realize that I needed to take out that first part, referring to the dataset and instead just needed to refer to the column. Yes, it works now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are likely looking for is the summarise function which is also part of dplyr. A quick distinction between mutate and summarise is below.

mutate() either changes an existing column or adds a new one.

summarise() calculates a single value (per group).

```
iris %>% 
group_by(Species) %>% 
summarise(max_sepal = max(Sepal.Length, na.rm = TRUE))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
Species          max_sepal
<fct>             <dbl>
1 setosa           5.8
2 versicolor       7  
3 virginica        7.9
```

You can some more examples of this below

https://community.rstudio.com/t/what-is-difference-between-mutate-and-summarise/23103/3

Comment: Thank you for your help with this. I was actually wanting to add another column so did prefer using the mutate function. but didn't realize I needed to take out the reference to the dataset and just refer to the column. thanks - this works now.

Comment: @AliData. Are you able to mark the answers as correct?